# non-ASCII characters in Julia sourcefiles (e.g. θ) come out mojibake (e.g. Îÿ) using '\lstinputlisting{}' in LaTeX

Tags: latex, julia, listings

I would like to include some Julia source in a LaTeX doc. I am familiar with the 'listings' package, and have crafted a decent 'lstdefinelanguage'. But I am having trouble with non-ASCII characters in the jl. I have played around with various 'lstset' and 'inputenc' options like 'extendedchars' and 'utf8' to no avail. I am using TeXShop on a Mac. Has anyone cracked this?

Comment: It seems that your tool expect that file is not utf8 encoded. Maybe put something like `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` somwere could help?

Comment: That's what I was trying to do with the inputenc option...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `literate` option although it requires some set-up work. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\lstset{literate=
    {δ}{{$\delta$}}1
    {ϵ}{{$\epsilon$}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
function f()
    ϵϵϵϵϵ = 1
    xxxxx = 3
    δδδδδ = 2
    ϵ + x + δ
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you -- that worked! I had been playing around with `literate` before without success; but in putting in your example I discovered that my text editor was using Latin 9 encoding rather than UTF-8.